# Squareup error in production (AWS EC2): TypeError: window.Square.payments is not a function

Tags: javascript, django, square

I've implemented the square payment just like the documentation indicated and I'm getting an error when loading the page and the card section does not come up.

It's a Django project, hosted in AWS EC2. We do use cloudflare but I've disabled it and it still doesn't work. Works perfectly in localhost.

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: window.Square.payments is not a function`

This is my implementation

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://web.squarecdn.com/v1/square.js"></script>

<!-- Square payment scripts -->
<script>
  const appId = "{{APPID}}";
  const locationId = "{{LOCATIONID}}";

   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async function () {
    if (!window.Square) {
      throw new Error('Square.js failed to load properly');
    }

    const payments = window.Square.payments(appId, locationId); // This is where the error is thrown
    ...
    }
```

Comment: No errors in console or network tab?

Comment: The error is shown in the console, no error in the network tab.

Comment: Can you check the generated HTML source code (right click -> View source)? Something might be modifying the script tags. I just tried your code in a React frontend and it works as expected.

Comment: This is the only think I noticed, but it's the cloudflare code added. Otherwise everything seems to be fine. Would you be more helpful to upload the file here?`<script type="de042f8f9fa143854c02c543-text/javascript" src="https://web.squarecdn.com/v1/square.js"></script>`

Comment: I've compared with the generated file in localhost where it works perfectly

Comment: Yeah, that breaks it. It seems the browser no longer fetches that script. Try removing the `type` attribute, it's not really needed.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that cloudflare did not load the file properly and I add to add `data-cfasync="false"` the the script to load the square.js file. It works perfectly now.

Thanks to @yuriy636 for pointing me to the right direction.